# When using sp_executesql with temp tables is the recommended approach to use global temp tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have the following structure using dynamic sql with variables and temporary tables:

```
DECLARE @X AS INT = 1;
DECLARE @Y AS INT = 1;
DECLARE @Z AS INT = 1;

DECLARE @S AS NVARCHAR(500) = 
           N' SELECT @P+@Q+@R AS ANSWER INTO #X'

EXEC sp_executesql 
    @stmt   = @S,
    @params = N'@P AS INT,@Q AS INT,@R AS INT',
    @P  = @X,
    @Q  = @Y,
    @R  = @Z; 

SELECT (ANSWER + 1) AS FINALANSWER
FROM #X
```

The temp table #x gets created in the scope sp_executesql so then using that data in subsequent code is not possible.

Is there a standard approach I need to take to make this work or should I switch to global temp tables?

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: @MitchWheat ok thanks Mitch I use that site a lot - second to MSDN. I'd not really thought of it as "sharing data between stored procedures" but I suppose that is EXACTLY what it is - just one of the procs is a built sql-server proc. Because both procs aren't created by myself and because `sp_executesql` is created by MS I'm wondering if there is a standard recommended approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have look at this using an OUTPUT parameter to retreieve the value

**Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SomeProc
@X INT = NULL,
@Y INT = NULL,
@Z INT = NULL,
@Result INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @S AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @S = N' SELECT @Result =  @X + @Y + @Z'

EXEC sp_executesql  @S
                   ,N'@X INT,@Y INT,@Z INT, @Result INT OUTPUT'
                   , @X, @Y, @Z, @Result OUTPUT 

END
```

**Execute Proc**

```
DECLARE @R INT;
EXECUTE SomeProc 
@X = 1, 
@Y = 1, 
@Z = 1,
@Result = @R OUTPUT

SELECT @R + 1 AS FinalAnswer
```

**Result**

```
FinalAnswer
4
```

**Edit**

Since you have mentioned in your comments that you will be returning a table from your proc in this case I would sugguest to do a simple `SELECT` inside the proc and get the results returned from you proc into a Temp table outside of the proc. something like this ...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Results
GO
CREATE TABLE #Results (Value INT)
GO

/* Execute Proc and insert into temp table */

INSERT INTO #Results (Value)
EXECUTE YourProc @Var1, @Var2 ....
```

Comment: @whytheq cheers I personally prefer OUTPUT params over temp tables as for creating new objects to store data requires two extra steps  1) checking for existance if does exist then drop and create 2) once your done with them dont forgot to drop them. using OUTPUT params saves you a lot of this unnecessary work :)

Comment: ... true - my mistake though as in OP I've used a scalar example but in our production environment we need to return a table

Answer (score 3):

I would just create the temp table first. Inner execution scopes can see temp tables from outer scopes:

```
DECLARE @X AS INT = 1;
DECLARE @Y AS INT = 1;
DECLARE @Z AS INT = 1;

CREATE TABLE #X (ANSWER INT)

DECLARE @S AS NVARCHAR(500) = 
           N'INSERT INTO #X(ANSWER) SELECT @P+@Q+@R'

EXEC sp_executesql 
    @stmt   = @S,
    @params = N'@P AS INT,@Q AS INT,@R AS INT',
    @P  = @X,
    @Q  = @Y,
    @R  = @Z; 

SELECT (ANSWER + 1) AS FINALANSWER
FROM #X
```